# how to use `separate` function from stringr to split the column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data that look like that:

```
 [1] "average_on_return_belief_01" "average_on_return_belief_02"
 [3] "average_on_return_belief_03" "average_on_return_belief_04"
 [5] "average_on_return_belief_05" "average_on_return_belief_06"
 [7] "average_on_return_belief_07" "average_on_return_belief_08"
 [9] "average_on_return_belief_09" "average_on_return_belief_10"
[11] "average_on_return_belief_11" "average_on_return_belief_12"
[13] "average_on_send_belief_01"   "average_on_send_belief_02"  
[15] "average_on_send_belief_03"   "average_on_send_belief_04"  
[17] "average_on_send_belief_05"   "average_on_send_belief_06"  
[19] "average_on_send_belief_07"   "average_on_send_belief_08"  
[21] "average_on_send_belief_09"   "average_on_send_belief_10"  
[23] "average_on_send_belief_11"   "average_on_send_belief_12"  
[25] "sender_decision_01"          "sender_decision_02"         
[27] "sender_decision_03"          "sender_decision_04"         
[29] "sender_decision_05"          "sender_decision_06"         
[31] "sender_decision_07"          "sender_decision_08"         
[33] "sender_decision_09"          "sender_decision_10"         
[35] "sender_decision_11"          "sender_decision_12"         
...
```

I need to use `separate` function from `stringr` (for `pivot_longer` `names_sep` param) to split these into two columns: `parameter name` and `code`.

so I have a list of 'prefixes'

```
to_retrieve <- c("average_on_return_belief_",
"average_on_send_belief_" ,
"sender_decision_",
"return_decision_" ,
"receiver_belief_",
"sender_belief_" )
```

but have no clue how to feed them into a `separate` in such a way that it would split an input of `sender_belief_01` into something like `c('sender_belief', '01')`

Any ideas or hints would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to pass `to_retrieve` explicitly. You may use `extract` to divide a column into two new columns using regular expressions.

```
tidyr::extract(df, cols, c('col1', 'col2'), '(.*)_(.*)')

#   col1                     col2 
#   <chr>                    <chr>
# 1 average_on_return_belief 01   
# 2 average_on_return_belief 02   
# 3 average_on_return_belief 11   
# 4 average_on_return_belief 12   
# 5 average_on_send_belief   01   
# 6 average_on_send_belief   02   
# 7 average_on_send_belief   11   
# 8 average_on_send_belief   12   
# 9 sender_decision          01   
#10 sender_decision          02   
#11 sender_decision          11   
#12 sender_decision          12
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(cols = c("average_on_return_belief_01", "average_on_return_belief_02", 
"average_on_return_belief_11", "average_on_return_belief_12", 
"average_on_send_belief_01", "average_on_send_belief_02", "average_on_send_belief_11", 
"average_on_send_belief_12", "sender_decision_01", "sender_decision_02", 
"sender_decision_11", "sender_decision_12")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks! but how do they get the last '_', and do not stop at the first one in something like 'average_on_send_belief_01'?

Comment: Because regex is greedy if we use `.*` meaning it will capture as much as possible hence it goes to the last `'_'` and doesn't stop at first one.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround in `separate` to match the `_` before the digits (`\\d+$`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, cols, into = c("col1", "col2"), "_(?=\\d+$)")
# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   col1                     col2 
#   <chr>                    <chr>
# 1 average_on_return_belief 01   
# 2 average_on_return_belief 02   
# 3 average_on_return_belief 11   
# 4 average_on_return_belief 12   
# 5 average_on_send_belief   01   
# 6 average_on_send_belief   02   
# 7 average_on_send_belief   11   
# 8 average_on_send_belief   12   
# 9 sender_decision          01   
#10 sender_decision          02   
#11 sender_decision          11   
#12 sender_decision          12
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(cols = c("average_on_return_belief_01", "average_on_return_belief_02", 
"average_on_return_belief_11", "average_on_return_belief_12", 
"average_on_send_belief_01", "average_on_send_belief_02",
"average_on_send_belief_11", 
"average_on_send_belief_12", "sender_decision_01", "sender_decision_02", 
"sender_decision_11", "sender_decision_12")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option using `tstrsplit`, following the same regex pattern with [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095844/12158757)

```
setDT(df)[, setNames(tstrsplit(cols, "_(?=\\d+$)", perl = TRUE), c("col1", "col2"))]
```

which gives

```
                        col1 col2
 1: average_on_return_belief   01
 2: average_on_return_belief   02
 3: average_on_return_belief   11
 4: average_on_return_belief   12
 5:   average_on_send_belief   01
 6:   average_on_send_belief   02
 7:   average_on_send_belief   11
 8:   average_on_send_belief   12
 9:          sender_decision   01
10:          sender_decision   02
11:          sender_decision   11
12:          sender_decision   12
```